# split a mysql dump file and save the split files on another server?

Tags: database, split, mysql

I have a mysql file and it is 13 GB in space. I want to split it into 4 parts so that I can compress it. But there is no enough space on server to keep the split file ( collectively 13 GB).

Is it possible to split the file and save it on another server?

like 
`split -b 40k myfile | username@domain_name 'cat > /tmp/sppli_file_'`

Please suggest.

Comment: @jordanm: In have only 10 GB space on server and I cannot save original file and zipped file both!!! but file to be compressed is 13 GB.... I guess `zip` will only compress files less than of 4 GB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure; does the other server have `sshd` installed and enabled?

You can pipe the file over SSH to the other machine and split it there:

```
cat myfile | ssh user@othermachine split -b 40k
```

If your version of `split` has the `--filter` option, you can even compress the splits on the fly:

```
cat myfile | ssh user@othermachine split -b 40k --filter='gzip > $FILE.gz'
```

Comment: split by default would generate file names with prefix `x`, like xaa, xab, xac, ... To set your own prefix run split as `split -b 40k - myfile` (the - means reading the data to split from stdin)

Comment: and please let me know how to save it on temp directory of the other machine

Comment: To save to temp directory use prefix `/tmp/myfile` (or `/var/tmp/myfile`)